# Resharper - Format <!DOCTYPE>

Tags: xml, resharper, indentation, doctype

Resharper (2020.1.3) formats xml `<!DOCTYPE>` element differently from Visual Studio 2019. Formatting an XML document gives the following output:

**Pure Visual Studio 2019 (no Resharper):**

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
    <!ENTITY XML "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml">
    <!ENTITY XMLNames "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names">
]>
```

**Resharper 2020.1.3**

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
<!ENTITY XML "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml">
<!ENTITY XMLNames "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names">
]>
```

Please notice different indentations of `<!ENTITY>` inside `<!DOCTYPE>`.

How do I configure Resharper either to indent `<!ENTITY>` the same way Visual Studio does or at least to not touch `<!DOCTYPE>` at all and leave the code as it is (indented). If that is not possible then how can I configure Visual Studio to use Resharper's style or to not touch `<!DOCTYPE>` when formatting an XML document.

In another words, the goal is to make the formatting consistent. Sure, Resharper still does way better code clean up than Visual Studio, i.e. Resharper does some additional formatting. But those are not overridden by Visual Studio if another developer (without Resharper) formats the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper does not have formatter rules for <!ENTITY> and <!DOCTYPE>. I filed [a feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-483375).